# Drizzle installation end up with errors

Tags: npm, scrypt, drizzle

I have followed the [this](https://truffleframework.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-drizzle-and-react) tutorial from Truffle official page, First few steps goes smoothly and when i tried to install `drizzle` on client directory as per the tutorial says it ended up with this error message,

[image]

before this error message it has error with `typescript` package so i installed it manually, and this one is with `scrypt`.
previously it was about VS build tools, now it is with `Scrypt` package, with missing some files.

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, it seems `scrypt` package supports node 11v only.